# Disable Form Submit jquery on missing / or value != '' && value !='0'

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to disable form submit with jQuery, i have checked the jQuery.validate.js plugin
but it does not regcognize my txtQty[] array:

```
rules : { 'txtQty[]' : {required: true, minlength: 2} }
```

but that didn´t work

heres my current Code which needs to stop submitting if

```
txtQty[] == '0' && txtQty == ''
```

Code:

```
    $("form#frmCart").submit(function(e) { 
    var err = false;
    var hidCartId = [];
    var hidProductId = [];
    var txtQty = [];
    var artSize = [];
    $("input[name='txtQty\\[\\]']").each(function(index) {
            if($(this).val() != '' || $(this).val() != '0'){
                txtQty.push($(this).attr('value'));
            } else {
                alert("Empty val");
                err = true;
                $(this).focus();
                e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the submit
                return false; // Exit the .each loop


            }
    });

    $("input[name='hidProductId\\[\\]']").each(function(index) { 
            hidProductId.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    $("input[name='hidCartId\\[\\]']").each(function(index) {   
            hidCartId.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    $("select[name='articleSize\\[\\]']").each(function(index) { 
        if($(this).val() != $(this).attr('value')){
            artSize.push($(this).val());
        } else {
            artSize.push($(this).attr('value'));
        }
    });
    if(err === true){
                e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the submit
                return false; // Exit the .each loop
    } 

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "cart.php?action=update",
        data: {hidCartId: hidCartId, hidProductId: hidProductId, txtQty: txtQty, size: artSize},
        success: function(result){
            $('#content-container').html(result);       
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

even the alert does not get fired.......
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first .each, change || to &&